# Mysql keywords with rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, db2

My one column name is "usage" and it's conflicting with mysql keywords.

To solve out that issue i was passing usage like `usage` with ActiveRecord. That solved my problem.

CsvHeader.find(:all,:conditions => ["`usage` = ?",usage]))

Right now i am attaching db2 as my database.
db2 is not accepting &&. so i have replaced && with and.
Another problem db2 causing with ` backsinglequote.

This working with mysql but not with db2.

CsvHeader.find(:all,:conditions => ["`usage` = ?",usage]))

Any help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
CsvHeader.all :conditions => { :usage => usage }
```

or

```
CsvHeader.find_all_by_usage usage
```

You can combine multiple and'ed conditions into one hash or by using `find_all_by_XXX_and_YYY`...